# How do I insertData in a header in TYPO3 CMS?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I would like to use data like "Hello {TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name}!" as a content element heading in TYPO3 (10.x). I managed to accomplish this for the element's bodytext using the following TypoScript setup:

`lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.insertData = 1`

How would I go about doing this for a header?

Comment: You do not need to it with TypoScript. You can create a viewHelper for that which gets all the user object on the FrontEnd. You can use the images as well. https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-get-the-frontend-user-object-in-the-frontend . The next question is: What do you mena you need it in Header? which header?

Comment: Yes, I know all about that. However, the question is not how to do this as an integrator. I'm looking for a way to allow an editor to insert a code like ````{TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name}```` into any content element header, which would be automatically replaced. The TS I mentioned above does this for bodytext. My question is how to do it for header.

Comment: Since none of the code that actually renders those values by default can deal with caches properly, you would still have to rewrite those parts to make sure that this kind of "user specific input" will not show cached variants to the users.

So unless you want to disable caching completely, which is IMHO never a good idea, it won't be just the "insertData" problem, you would have to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just put that data into a `lib` making use of a replacement method and access those values with the `f:cObject` view helper. So you can make sure only data gets "inserted" that won't be a security risk.

```
lib.myHeader = TEXT
lib.myHeader {
    field = header
    stdWrap.replacement {
        10 {
            search = USER_FIRST_NAME
            replace.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name
        }
        20 {
            search = USER_LAST_NAME
            replace.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|last_name
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Replacement.html

This part is taken from the Fluid that renders the header in the bootstrap package:

```
    <f:case value="1">
        <h1 class="{class} {positionClass}">
            <f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">
                <span>
                    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myHeader" data="{data}" />
                </span>
            </f:link.typolink>
        </h1>
    </f:case>
```

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/Header/Header.html

I guess you can modify the rest of the partial based on that example.

Still you should be aware of caching issues, since that data might get rendered once and then show the first name for each of the users. So make sure that the blocks containing those values will either get cached for each user or not get cached at all.

Comment: Yes, I know all about that. However, the question is not how to do this in a template. I'm looking for a way to allow an editor to insert a code like ````{TSFE:fe_user|user|first_name}```` into any content element header, which would be automatically replaced. The TS I mentioned above does this for bodytext. My question is how to do it for header.

Comment: If this is about replacements and placeholders inserted by editors, you should go for something less complicated than the official TypoScript syntax and do the replacement within one go for the whole page instead.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Replacement.html

Comment: If you just want to modify the way headers are rendered, this depends on the frontend output variant you are using - i.e. Fluid Styled Content, Bootstrap Package or your own custom Sitepackage, since each of them might render things completely differently than the other.

Comment: Maybe. But I'm sure there's a way to set a renderFunc on headers just as well as on bodytext. It's just that my TYPO3 skills are somewhat rusty coming back after a few years (last version I used back then was somewhere in the 7.x range, I think).

Comment: Bootstrap package, in my case

Comment: Still you should go fo the replacement functionality, since just doing insertData will give editors access to a whole bunch of data they should NEVER get access to AND they should definitely NOT show in the frontend.

I will modify my answer to include a solution without such a security hole.